# Modelsim: Does a 'X' in a std_logic_vector affect the other bits in the vector?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim, quartus

I have a `Signal myVec : std_logic_vector(8 down 0)`. Modelsim shows this value: `0X000010`. So `bit(6)` is Undefined. Does this affect other bits for example to `bit(1)`?

I change the state with the following:

```
    if myVec(1) = '0' then
      --change the state to x 
    else
      --change state to y 
    end if;
```

The problem is that the state always switches to `y` and I don't know why.
Could it be that `bit(6)` of `myVec` has an affect to `bit(1)` or the other bits?

Comment: It's really a bad practice to have undefined states (unless you did it on purpose to meet your requirements). This said, if your condition depends only on a given bit of a vector then it can't depend on the others.

Answer (score 1):

'X' is *not* undefined. std_logic_1164 defines 'X' as "Forcing  Unknown". *IF* required, 'U' is used for "uninitialized" =~ undefined.

'X' actually means that a signal could not be properly resolved, e.g. it is driven by both '1' and '0'. If you change the type from `std_logic` to `std_ulogic`, you will probably see where this happens.

But your question: Unless implemented differently, the individual elements in an array do not affect each other.